# less strict type language option

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I have a function in Haskell:

```
import qualified Codec.Picture as Juicy

--juicyLoad :: FilePath -> IO (Vector Word8)
juicyLoad file = do
    image <- Juicy.readPng file

    case image of
        Left err -> undefined
        Right (Juicy.ImageRGB8 (Juicy.Image w h dat)) ->
            return dat
```

GHC infers the type to be `FilePath -> IO (Vector Word8)`, which is what I want. When I actually define that in the source file (`juicyLoad :: FilePath -> IO (Vector Word8)`), there is an error: `Couldn't match expected type 'Vector Word8' with actual type 'Vector(PixelBaseComponent PixelRGB8'.`

This seems like a job for a `{-# LANGUAGE x #-}` option, I just don't know which one

Comment: You might want to add your `imports` and mention library versions.

Comment: Please post the full code, including imports. This works for me when I added sensible imports, so I guess you have made a mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different versions of `Vector`. I was able to fix this by explicitly importing the same one that is inferred by GHC.

```
import qualified Codec.Picture as Juicy
import Data.Vector.Storable
import GHC.Word
```

And declaring the type like this:

```
juicyLoad :: FilePath -> IO (Vector Word8)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was my importing of the `Vector` type. I was importing `Data.Vector`, the correct import is `Data.Vector.Storable`.